# How to access value from nested JSON through gson in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I'm looking to access the value for flower_id id in this JSON. I want to access it through gson or by the JSONObject. Here are my classes:

```
class Json2(val result: Result2) {
}
class Result2(val status:String, val featured_items: Array<FeaturedItems> , val trending_items:Array<TrendingItems> ) {
}
class FeaturedItems(val pic:String, val price:String, val item_name:String, val shop_name:String, val flower_id:String) {
}
class TrendingItems(val pic:String,val price:String, val item_name:String, val shop_name:String, val flower_id:String) {
}
```

Here is what I've written in the success part of the AsyncHttpResponseHandler():

```
var jsonInfo2 = mutableListOf<FeaturedItems>()
    var jsonInfo3 = mutableListOf<TrendingItems>()

                override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, responseBody: ByteArray?) {

                    if (responseBody != null) { val charset2 = Charsets.UTF_8

                        val json2 = String(responseBody, charset2)
                        val gson2 = Gson().newBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

                        val homescreenresult = gson2.fromJson<Json2>(json2, genericType<Json2>())

                        jsonInfo2.addAll(homescreenresult.result.featured_items)

                        jsonInfo3.addAll(homescreenresult.result.trending_items)
```

This is the JSON from which I need to access flower_id.

`{ "result": { "status": "1", "top_icons": [ { "record_id": 0, "title": "", "status": true }, { "record_id": 1, "title": "Categories", "status": true }, { "record_id": 2, "title": "Shops", "status": true }, { "record_id": 3, "title": "Occasions", "status": true }, { "record_id": 4, "title": "Offers", "status": true } ], "banners": [ { "banner_id": "ubZFZJaaiEc=", "skip_button": false,  "bg_color": "", "button_bg_color": "", "button_text_color": "", "button_text": "", "screen": "", "shop_id": "208", "shop_name": "Dear Cocoa", "occasion_id": "", "occasion_name": "", "item_id": "9ua2ojMRCWY=", "section_id": "2", "banner_text": "", "youtube_video_id": "" }, { "banner_id": "WrHTW4q7Aro=", "skip_button": false, "bg_color": "", "button_bg_color": "", "button_text_color": "", "button_text": "", "screen": "", "shop_id": "", "shop_name": "", "occasion_id": "97", "occasion_name": "Gergean", "item_id": "", "section_id": "2", "banner_text": "", "youtube_video_id": "" }, { "banner_id": "DFozQw8G9h0=", "skip_button": false, "bg_color": "", "button_bg_color": "", "button_text_color": "", "button_text": "", "screen": "", "shop_id": "592", "shop_name": "2u Store", "occasion_id": "", "occasion_name": "", "item_id": "", "section_id": "1", "banner_text": "", "youtube_video_id": "" } ], "sections": [ { "section_id": -1, "name": "New",  "custom_val": "shops-new", "status": true }, { "section_id": 1, "name": "Flowers",   "custom_val": "1", "status": true }, { "section_id": 2, "name": "Confections", "custom_val": "2", "status": true }, { "section_id": 3, "name": "Gifts", "custom_val": "3", "status": true } ], "featured_items": [ { "record_id": "Aizh3yL5+jw=", "flower_id": "3S8bQ9d31yw=", "product_id": 283946, "item_name": "25% OFF - Vero", "shop_name": "Flower and Beyond",  "currency": "KWD", "price_per": 26.25, "price": "KWD 26.250", "old_price": "KWD 35.000", "sell_by_min": 1.0, "max_quantity": 6, "sell_by_unit": "1.0", "sell_by": "quantity", "same_day_delivery": true, "distance": "0 km" },`

As you can see both trending and featured items have flower_id. I want to access all the flower ids in the array of both classes and use them accordingly whenever either of the two items are clicked on.

Comment: What's the specific issue, in other words, given that GSON/JSON libs are pretty well documented, what isn't working?

Comment: I'm unable to access the value of flower_id from this JSON. I'm using the model class method to access values of other keys which are not in the list. I don't know how to access the value of keys whch are inside the List of arrays. For example: "featured_items" has list of arrays. From that I want the value for "flower_id" , to store it in a variable because I need that value to pass it to an API which will give me further results.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse JSON with Gson you need to define your own JsonObject classes according to the flowers JSON structure you have.
These classes can be nested. One "Json class" can contain another as its field. For example: `data class YourJsonClass(var id: Int, var data: List<YourNestedJsonClass>)`

 Then you need to simply parse JSON like this: `Gson().fromJson(yourJsonText, YourJsonClass::class.java)`

 Gson parses it all automatically according to the structure you wrote.

Comment: I have already tried that. 
                        val charset4 = Charsets.UTF_8

                        val json4 = String(responseBody, charset4)

                        val gson4 = Gson().newBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

                        val itemscreenresult = gson4.fromJson<Json4>(json4, genericType<Json4>())

                        jsonInfo6.addAll(itemscreenresult.result.data)

Comment: But I need Json4 to access other values. and due to that i cant access values from the other class.

Comment: Can you please help ?

Comment: You say you tried this but i dont see your classes. Here's a guide for you: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Comment: I have edited my code and shown the classes as well.